# Mathematica Complains about Non Symmetric Covariance matrix, when it's not the case

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics, fitting

I was doing some fitting with Mathematica7 using NonlinearModelFit. It's quite long the program to do the fit and that's why I am not displaying here ...

It goes ok, and I can get the fit parameters as well as the covariance matrix

```
In[81]:= {Subscript[a, 0], Subscript[a, 1]}/.fitCCBA34["BestFitParameters"]

In[78]:= fitCCBA34["CovarianceMatrix"]
```

When testing it is Symmetric, it goes ok, as should be by construction of the matrix:

```
In[80]:= SymmetricMatrixQ[b] 
Out[80]= True
```

However, it turns out, that, when trying to get some Multinormal distribution of the parameters, it complains about the matrix which is non-symmetric ...

```
In[84]:= MultinormalDistribution[{Subscript[a, 0], Subscript[a, 
   1]} /. fitCCBA34[
   "BestFitParameters"], {{fitCCBA34["CovarianceMatrix"][[1, 1]], 
   fitCCBA34["CovarianceMatrix"][[1, 2]]}, {fitCCBA34[
     "CovarianceMatrix"][[2, 1]], 
   fitCCBA34["CovarianceMatrix"][[2, 2]]}}]

During evaluation of In[84]:= MultinormalDistribution::cmsym: The covariance matrix must be symmetric. >>

Out[84]= MultinormalDistribution[{0.275723, 
  0.246948}, {{0.00001521, -0.0000535383}, {-0.0000535383, 11.6061}}]
```

Of course, if now you do copy paste, it works perfectly, so I guess it's some numerical issue, any clue about how to fix this?
I need to encode this inside a function rather than copy paste each time ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The routines [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13823) might be useful to you...

Comment: It's hard to know without some data. But, wouldn't `fitCCBA34["CovarianceMatrix"` already return the matrix? I mean, why all the indexing?

Comment: @Pablo Please check that your matrix is definite positive. The one above in your example is.

Comment: @Rojo Well, I only needed 2 elements of the covariance matrix in this case to do some montecarlo, so it was faster creating the montecarlo with just the parameters I needed, (sorry for the confusion)

Comment: @chris I have checked, the problem is that while my matrices are symmetric (by construction should be) and SymmetricMatrixQ[] confirms it, the MultiNormal distribution says it's not ... I am pretty sure that is some rounding error, cause I just found out that finishes when setting in:

`SetPrecission[expr,n]`

to some low n, so it's just about some numerical problem, however, changing the precission changes a little bit the results ...

Comment: @Pablo but you are aware that symmetric is not enough right? All eigenvalues need to be positive.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for your suggestion, I freaked out doing some similar things not working, but finaly just taking `(fitCCBA34["CovarianceMatrix"] + Transpose[fitCCBA34["CovarianceMatrix"]])/2` solved the problem without spoiling precission

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @chris Yes, I am, is just that mathematica was complaining about symmetric only ..
Indeed sometimes complains about non-singularity but keeps on working ... the point is that sometimes the errors as well as the coefficients of the fit are quite small, then the determinant is too small ...
Ir seems to me like this random distribution has some limited precision or some numerical issue, not pretty sure .. Thanks for the comment ;)